# Flourinefx: Could not find a suitable method with name

Tags: .net, apache-flex, flourinefx

I'm having trouble with an old perfectly working flourinefx application after I reinstalled my computer.

For certain function calls (I think those that include custom objects) I get:

```
2013-01-15 19:03:53,616 [27] ERROR FluorineFx.MethodHandler - Could not find a suitable method with name GetTodayView
2013-01-15 19:03:53,616 [27] ERROR FluorineFx.MethodHandler - Displaying verbose logging information
2013-01-15 19:03:53,616 [27] ERROR FluorineFx.MethodHandler - Checking GetTodayView(query(Query))
2013-01-15 19:03:53,616 [27] ERROR FluorineFx.MethodHandler - query(Query) did not match value "Offerta.DAL.Queries.Query" (Query)
2013-01-15 19:03:53,633 [27] ERROR FluorineFx.Messaging.Endpoints.Filter.ProcessFilter - Could not find a suitable method with name GetTodayView
FluorineFx.Exceptions.FluorineException: Could not find a suitable method with name GetTodayView
   at FluorineFx.MethodHandler.GetMethod(Type type, String methodName, IList arguments, Boolean exactMatch, Boolean throwException, Boolean traceError)
   at FluorineFx.MethodHandler.GetMethod(Type type, String methodName, IList arguments, Boolean exactMatch, Boolean throwException)
   at FluorineFx.MethodHandler.GetMethod(Type type, String methodName, IList arguments, Boolean exactMatch)
   at FluorineFx.MethodHandler.GetMethod(Type type, String methodName, IList arguments)
   at FluorineFx.Messaging.Endpoints.Filter.ProcessFilter.Invoke(AMFContext context)
```

Anyone seen this type of behaviour before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a rare issue with FlourineFX and threading. read the following blog post:
http://jdecuyper.github.com/blog/FluorineFx-Could-Not-Find-A-Suitable-Method.html